# Parsing base 2^32 numbers to decimal (For theorically unlimited numbers)

Tags: binary, precision, unsigned, double-precision, bigint

I am working on a C++ problem where I have to print my class.
My class stores and does arithmetic and logic operations on theorically unlimited long numbers. It has an array of unsigned ints to hold the number. For example:
If the number is {a*(2^32) + b} , the class stores it as {array[0]=b , array[1]=a}.
So it is like a number of base (2^32). The problem is how do i convert this number to decimal so i can print it? Simply {a*(2^32) + b} will not do because it doesnt fit into unsigned int. I do not have to store the decimal number but just print it.

**What i have got so far**

I have thought of firstly converting the number to binary (which is an easy task) then printing it. But same problem arises because there is still no big enough variable to hold the multiplication.

**Wild thought**

I wonder if I can use my own class to hold the multiplication and with some iterative method do the printing?
I also wonder if this can be solved with some use of logarithmics?

Note: I am not allowed to use other libraries or other long types like double and longer.
Although I say this is for theorically unlimited numbers it would help if I could just find the way to print array of size 2. Then I can think about longer numbers.

Comment: You could iteratively divide by the place and mod by 10 to get each digit of the number and print it. b % 10 for ones, (b / 10) % 10 for the tens, etc and do that first for b, then for a. EDIT: er... reverse that order :P

Comment: @Murkaeus Thank you very much. I didnt understand what you meant at first but now I implemented it and it works well:)